# How do you derive a type $∃e(e)$ in terms of universally quantified types, without invoking Void initially?

Tags: type-theory, first-order-logic, curry-howard

I wrote a "proof" for this, and though it was enough to convince myself, there are a few things that bother me about it. Primarily I'm not sure about the loose way in which I'm swapping between first-order logic and the Curry-Howard correspondence, and some ancient and brief exposure to first-order logic as an undergraduate. I'm looking to keep the proof fairly intuitive, and avoid any overly clever invocations if possible (though I don't mind hearing about them).

I'm using a possibly non-standard convention that the syntax $∃e(e)$ means $∃e(P(e))$ where $P(e)$ means there exist a value of type $e$. Let $\texttt{Void}$ denote a type devoid of any values, and assume it can be expressed as $∀a(a)$ in the type system, which seems a legitimate take on affairs as it would be seemingly impossible to construct a value simultaneously inhabiting every type. Then a function from $T → \texttt{Void}$ is equivalent to $¬T$ by Curry-Howard, I believe.

Rather than going about it the hard way and trying to find a universal-only sentence that is implied by $∃e(e)$, then proving a logical equivalence, I'll start with a universally quantified type I've been given by [an oracle](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type), then show how this implies $∃e(e)$.

$$
\begin{multline}
\shoveleft
\begin{aligned}
∀r[∀a(a → r) → r] \\
∀r∀a(a → r) → ∀r(r) \\
∀r∀a(a → r) → \texttt{Void} \\
¬∀r∀a(a → r) \\
∃r[¬∀a(a → r)] \\
∃r[∃a(¬(a → r))] \\
∃r[∃a(¬(¬a∨r))] \\
∃r[∃a(a∧¬r)] \\
\text{(provable identities) }  ∃r[∃a(a)∧¬r] \\ 
\text{(eliminate conjunction) } ∃r[∃a(a)] \\ 
\text{(eliminate redundant quantifier) } ∃a(a)
\end{aligned}
\end{multline}
$$

(Apologies for the Unicode symbols, I gather it isn't the norm, but I'm trying to collect some notes in a markdown document.)

Comment: Perhaps it is best to show equivalence, though, in which case this is only one side of the coin.

Comment: If you want a inhabitant of a type in some type theory, you should be clearer about what type theory you're using and you should endeavor to use notation that formalized in a system for which you can reference, preferably a common one like [ITT](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory-intuitionistic/). I think you intend $\exists e(e)$ to mean something like $\exists T:\mathcal U.T$ or $\Sigma T:\mathcal U.T$ where $\mathcal U$ is a universe. If so, it is easy to provide an inhabitant of it as you just need some type with an inhabitant, e.g. $\Pi T:\mathcal U.T\to T$.